# Fullscreen Taskbar Removal

Tags: fullscreen

I am having trouble removing the taskbar while switching to fullscreen in games. It used to automatically remove them, but now the taskbar stays while blocking off a section of the bottom Is there some setting I could have messed with?

Comment: Is this a specific game that you're having issues with? Sounds like you could have switched to windowed (or borderless windows) mode accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue when viewing fullscreen videos in my web browser.

Here is how I fixed it (it's only a temporary fix):

1. Right click on the taskbar, and click "Taskbar settings".
2. Select the option "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode".
3. Go back to whatever is fullscreen.

When you go out of fullscreen:

1. Put your mouse on the very bottom of the screen. The taskbar should reappear.
2. Click the "Settings" icon from hiding the taskbar.
3. Unselect the option "Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode". (then close Settings).

The part of the screen it cut off should now be visible again, although if you move your mouse to the bottom, the taskbar will temporarily be visible again.