# How do I hide the taskbar when in full screen mode?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, fullscreen

On other computers the taskbar automatically hides whenever I toggle full screen (e.g. for a Powerpoint presentation or for videos online).

However, on my Windows 10 computer, the taskbar is still visible when full screen is enabled.

I've tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1334497/fullscreen-taskbar-removal) option and I've tried to go to the task manager to reset the Windows Explorer (I don't have such an app open).

What can I do to hide the taskbar whenever Im in full screen mode?

Comment: You mean Auto Hide does not work on your Windows 10 machine?

Comment: I have the options 'Auto hide on desktop mode' and 'Auto hide on tablet mode', whenever I switch these options on, I still see the taskbar when I'm in full screen in Powerpoint or Youtube

Comment: Maybe try repairing your operating system.  (Microsoft Media Creation Link - Second link for the Repair)